# How to fix a broken static resource link image in Lightning Experience?

Tags: formula-field, case-object

We have a new custom field with the following formula and the image looks broken. Here's the formula:

```
IMAGE(CASE( Status ,
'New',("/resource/status_icons/status-new.png"),
'Open','/resource/status_icons/status-open.png',
'Pending','/resource/status_icons/status-pending.png',
'Escalated','/resource/status_icons/status-escalated.png',
'Resolved','/resource/status_icons/status-closed.png',
'Closed','/resource/status_icons/status-closed.png',''),'',22,22) + ' ' + Text(Status)
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work properly in classic? Its recommended to use static resource for images, if `status_icons` is not zipped static resource.

Comment: Why do you have a close parentheses at the end of status-new.png?

Comment: if you expose this field what do you see also share your static resource structure? I will request you to do inspect element to get an idea what is wrong in the path